issue while creating .aab file
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
ERROR:[drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_next] D:\ReactNativeApps\Drivista\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_next.png [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_next] D:\ReactNativeApps\Drivista\android\app\build\generated\res\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_next.png: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources
ERROR:[drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_previous] D:\ReactNativeApps\Drivista\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_previous.png [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_previous] D:\ReactNativeApps\Drivista\android\app\build\generated\res\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_previous.png: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources     .....................................

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_next] D:\ReactNativeApps\Drivista\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_next.png     [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_next] D:\ReactNativeApps\Drivista\android\app\build\generated\res\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_next.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_previous] D:\ReactNativeApps\Drivista\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_previous.pn...................

I am following this link. Can anyone please provide me better path or tell me what should i do next?
